# How to access session from struts form object

Tags: java, session, struts, struts-1

Might be a bit of a noob question, but can I access a variable stored on the session from within a struts Form object?

```
public class MyForm extends ActionForm {...}
```

Comment: request.getSession(). Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: as below: there is no request object available?

Comment: You need to set value to the form either in actionServlet (or) JSP. I don't think you can directly access request here (unless you do some customization).

Comment: you should post this as an answer @thinksteep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set value to the form either in actionServlet (or) JSP. I don't think you can directly access request here (unless you do some customization).

Answer (score 4):

We have developed and maintained a very large project using Struts 1. I know your problem, we have an `ActionContext` class, with an `ActionContextFilter`, the filter binds the request and response objects to current thread using a `ThreadLocal` member (and obviously it unbinds them at the end of the process).

Now we can access request, response and ... using `ActionContext.getCurrentContext().getRequest()` and `ActionContext.getCurrentContext().getResponse()`.

I believe the same thing can help you alot.

By the whole idea was from **Clinton Begin**'s (the author of iBatis) sample PetStore; He have built a good extension around Struts 1 in that sample. I recommend you to review the whole work.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve an attribute in the session by using the `HttpServletRequest`:

```
request.getSession(false).getAttribute("yourAttributeName");
```

Comment: there is no request object available in the struts Form object.

Comment: It is in the validate method, but I guess that's not where you'd like to access it. I should have asked you to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Have'nt tried at home but you may use:

```
private HttpServletRequest request;

public void reset(ActionMapping mapping, HttpServletRequest request) {
    this.request = request;
}
```

and store the request in a local field for later use as described above.